# How do I remove duplicates that have a difference of one word?

Tags: windows, regex, file-management, duplicate

I have a folder with thousands of zip files, many of which are the same but for different countries. E.g. I would have three files called:

- File 1 (USA)
- File 1 (World)
- File 1 (Europe)

How can I make it so that the world and europe get deleted. Also, i want priority. so that if there is only world and europe, world should be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption, that you don't care about the Country.  That is, all files will end up `* (USA)`.

- Use FileExplorer to select all Europe Files, Move them to Folder E.
- Then Move all World Files to Folder W.
- Rename both these sets of files to *(USA)
- Now Move Folder E files to the original folder, and Skip, when asked.
- Repeat with Folder W
- Delete Folders E and W